# D3 Collapsible Tree Container dynamically decrease/increase depending on the tree

Tags: angular, svg, d3.js

I have this code to render a collapsible tree chart using Angular 14 and D3.js:

```js
@ViewChild('chart', { static: true }) private chartContainer: ElementRef;
  tree: d3.TreeLayout<any>;
  svg: any;
  root: any;
  treeData: any;
  height: number;
  width: number;

  margin: any = { top: 1700, bottom: 0, left: 20, right: 0 };
  duration: number = 750;
  nodeWidth: number = 5;
  nodeHeight: number = 5;
  nodeRadius: number = 5;
  horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes: number = 5;
  verticalSeparationBetweenNodes: number = 20;
  nodes: any[];
  economicActivities: EconomicActivity[];
  links: any;

  renderTreeChart(data: any) {
    let element: any = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
      .attr('height', element.clientHeight)
      .append("g")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')');

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    this.tree = d3.tree()
      .size([this.height, this.width])
      .nodeSize([this.nodeWidth + this.horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes, this.nodeHeight + this.verticalSeparationBetweenNodes])
      .separation((a: any, b: any) => { return a.parent == b.parent ? 3 : 4 });

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    this.root = d3.hierarchy(data, (d: any) => { return d.children; });
    this.root.x0 = this.height / 2;
    this.root.y0 = 10;
    this.updateChart(this.root);
  }

  click = (d: any) => {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    this.updateChart(d);
  }


  updateChart(source: any) {
    let i = 0;
    this.treeData = this.tree(this.root);
    this.nodes = this.treeData.descendants();
    this.links = this.treeData.descendants().slice(1);
    this.nodes.forEach((d) => { d.y = d.depth * 180 }); //Distancia de nodo izquierdo a nodo derecho

    let node = this.svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(this.nodes, (d: any) => { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    let nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('transform', (d: any) => {
        return 'translate(' + source.y0 + ',' + source.x0 + ')';
      })
      .on('click', this.click);

    nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style('fill', (d: any) => {
        return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
      });

    nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr('dy', '.35em')
      .attr('x', (d: any) => {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr('text-anchor', (d: any) => {
        return d.children || d._children ? 'end' : 'start';
      })
      .style('font', '10px sans-serif')
      .style('text-decoration', (d: any) => {
        return d.data.economicActivityId ? 'underline' : 'none';
      })
      .style('cursor', (d: any) => {
        return d.data.economicActivityId ? 'pointer' : 'default';
      })
      .text((d: any) => { return d.data.name; })
      .on('click', (d: any) => {
        this.upsert(d.data)
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

    let nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

    nodeUpdate.transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr('transform', (d: any) => {
        return 'translate(' + d.y + ',' + d.x + ')';
      });

    nodeUpdate.select('svg.icon')
      .attr('r', 10)
      .style('stroke-width', '3px')
      .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
      .style('fill', (d: any) => {
        return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
      })
      .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

    nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
      .attr('r', 10)
      .style('stroke-width', '3px')
      .style('stroke', 'steelblue')
      .style('fill', (d: any) => {
        return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
      })
      .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

    let nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr('transform', (d: any) => {
        return 'translate(' + source.y + ',' + source.x + ')';
      })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select('circle')
      .attr('r', 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select('text')
      .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

    let link = this.svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(this.links, (d: any) => { return d.id; });

    let linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', 'g')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .style('stroke', '#ccc')
      .style('stroke-width', '2px')
      .attr('d', function (d: any) {
        let o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
        return diagonal(o, o);
      });

    let linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

    linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr('d', (d: any) => { return diagonal(d, d.parent); });

    link.exit().transition()
      .duration(this.duration)
      .attr('d', function (d: any) {
        let o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
        return diagonal(o, o);
      })
      .remove();

    this.nodes.forEach((d) => {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y;
    });

    function diagonal(s: any, d: any) {
      let path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                  C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                  ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                  ${d.y} ${d.x}`;
      return path;
    }
  }
}
```

I also have this on html and css:

```html
<div class="content" role="main">
  <div class="d3-chart container tree" #chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.d3-chart {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700vh;
}

.content {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

It works well, however the container (.d3-chart) and the svg height, do not increase/decrease depending on the tree height. What can I do to have the container and the svg increase/decrease depending on the tree height ? as the documentation: [https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree][1]
[1]: https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree